# mySQL into outfile strange behaviour

Tags: sql-injection, mysql, freebsd

I have sql-injection with file_priv=Y (root user) but I can only create file in /tmp and /var/tmp directories even when i have 777 permissions to destination folder - mysql server just won't create file (Errcode 13). Server runs freebsd 8.x and mysql 5.x. What could be the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Your MySQL server is also running as root?

Comment: @Technidev, no.

Comment: What is the destination path? The server must have read access to the whole path, and might need to have scan access also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to check:

- the [secure_file_priv](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) variable
- The server must have read access to the whole path, and might need to have scan access also (e.g. to write in /a/b/c, you need r-- access to both a and b, and -w- access to c, at least. Those could be r-x and -wx respectively).

Comment: Thanks, looks like it explains trouble. However I can't check this now, but will keep that in mind.

Comment: You're welcome, but I'd suggest you do not accept the answer until you verify it *is* correct. You may upvote it, but only accept if it *really* addresses your trouble. Others might stumble here when Googling and get mislead. Since I think you can't unaccept-then-accept-again, just come back and un-accept the answer if it turns out I was wrong... *and* remember detailing what *was* the actual cause (yes, I'm curious :-) ).

Comment: @Iserni, I can't upvote it, so i just accepted it. The problem is that I don't have access to server atm and do not know if I will, but your pretty good and I know what i should pay attention more carefully next time.